# Attach an excel file with an android app in a secured way

Tags: android, mysql, excel, apache-poi

I have an excel file with 4 worksheets and contains hundreds of formulas. Now I'm making an app where a user can write a specific name and that will go to my excel sheet and after all the calculation the result will be shown back in the app.

I went through many options but I dont know which fits the best.
I went through apache poi, jexcel and mysql.
The main thing is no user should be able to hack that excel file. That means if i add it in library then someone can surely extract the apk and get the resources.

Someone please help with this!

Comment: Put the file on a server, and have the app send requests, so the file is never on the device?

Comment: Yes, the file is not supposed to be on the device. Now I have already added this file on mysql server but the data in my excel is not permanent. It keeps on changing.